# Consumo de WebService de facturación electrónica - AFIP

Tags: c#, .net, webservice, vb6, framework

**Contexto:**
máquina virtual, VMWare Workstation 16 player
Sistema Operativo: Windows XP Profesional 2002 Service Pack 3
Base de datos: SQL Server 2005 RTM (Microsoft SQL Server Express Edition) on Windows 2000 Server
Desarrollos propios:

- Visual Basic 6.0 SP6
- Microsoft Visual Studio 2017, framwork 2.0

**Escenario:**
Tenemos un sistema de gestión de empresa de desarrollo propio. Entre otras cosas, este sistema emite comprobantes (facturas, notas de crédito, notas de débito, etc.).
Debido a una reglamentación de un ente impositivo nacional (AFIP: Administración General de Ingresos Públicos), todo comprobante debe incluir un código de autorización que AFIP provée mediante un webservice.
La operación es entonces que el webservice recibe información del comproabnte a emitir y devuelve el código mencionado.
El sistema, desarrolaldo en VB6 consume el webservice por medio de una librería (dll) desarrolalda en .net framework 2.0 e implementada como componemte COM. Y funciona normalmente.

**Problema:**
Hace un tiempo hubo un cambio en la estructura de datos que debe recibir el webservice y fue necesario actualizar el desarrollo ya hay algunos atributos nuevos y requeridos.
El problema se presenta porque el webervice solo soporta TLS1.2 y el sistema debe correr en windows xp debido al desarrollo en vb6.
Al intentar invocar el web service, éste no responde devolviendo un error de conexión.

**Cosas que hice.**
He estado investigando cómo solucionar este problema y he tomado algunas acciones.
Ya he instaldo las actualizaciones de windows indicadas por microsoft y he actualizado el registro de windows. Después de lago de trabajo pude ver finalmente la opción de TLS1.2 en las opciones avanzadas de internet, en el panel de control.
Algunos sitios que visité proponen cosas raras como "isntalar framwork 4.6" cuando no existe una versión para windows xp, y otras cosas que no pude hacer.
En algunas partes, leí que ya no es posible usar TLS1.2 desde windows xp y que debo migrar todo.
La reingeniería del sistema está iniciada, pero necesito resolver este problema.

Pero ahora tengo dos problemas.

- El sistema no se conecta, ahora el error el "protocolo no sportado"
- El sistema tampoco se conecta a la base de datos SQL devolviendo un error de SSL, incluso volviendo a deshabilitar TLA1.2. Es decir, ya no se conecta. La conexión se hace mediante una string estámdar: Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;User Id=user;Password=pass;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=database;Data Source=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\SQLEXPRESS,1433;

Finalmente la máquina virtual no es problema, tengo un snapshot, y acá van las preguntas:

- ¿es real que no existe manera de comunicar windwos xp mediante tls 1.2?
- ¿que puede haber pasado con la conexión a base de datos?
- cualquier ayuda o comentario sobre esto, será bienvenido.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Tratemos de evitar poner multiples preguntas dentro de una sola. No se que le paso a tu db, pero porque no podes poner otro sistema operativo, por mas que sea vb6?? alguna de las librerias necesarias no corre? porque vb6, deberia correr sin problemas. (en la mayoria de los casos)

Comment: Coincido con gbianchi. Cualquier aplicación VB6 debería correr en las versiones de windows actuales tanto 32bits como 64bits. A menos que tengas un escenario muy extraño donde utilices algún componente o librería de terceros que lo impida.

Comment: Les agradezco el interés, las respuestas y me disculpo por la consulta.
voy a investigar lo que me dicen y actualizaré el post.